# A Turing Machine that Doesn't Move to the left

Tags: complexity-theory, turing-machines

My question is if the following statement is true or false:

> Does every turing-recognized $B$ language has a turing machine $M$ that recognizes $B$ and fullfiles the following statement:
>
> For every word $w$ the belongs to $B$, $w \in B$, the writing-reading head **never moves to the left**?
>
> Notice that the condition is required only for words in the language. if $w \notin B$ then the head can move to the left as usual.

The statemet seems correct to me. I think I can simulate a regular $TM$ with this "special" $TM$, while saying that every time the head moves left, it will stay put. Couldn't prove it, though.

Comment: Can you construct a TM like that that accepts $a^nb^n$?

Comment: Are working tapes available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### False.

A Turing machine that can't move left can never write information on the tape, then go back to read it later. In other words, it can't store any information; it has no memory apart from its state.

This makes it into a finite state machine, which is significantly weaker than a Turing machine. (As `ratchet freak` points out in the comments, a finite state machine can't recognize the language $\{ 0^n 1^n | n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, while a Turing machine can.)

Note, however, that some Turing machines have multiple tapes. If you have another tape available, and can move left on that one, then there's no problem: just run once over the original tape and copy it onto your working tape, then run as normal, without ever moving the original head backward.

Answer (score 2):

If you only allow moving right (and no external memory), all your TM "knows" about the input already seen is the *finite* amount of information in its state. I.e., it can't do more than a finite state automaton.